Can one just read buffered bytes in io.BufferedReader?
In Python, the io.BufferedReader class has various methods to read bytes from a stream, using an internal buffer.  The read method may make various read calls to the underlying raw stream, the peek and read1 method will make at most one read call to the underlying raw stream.
Is there any way (say in Python 3.13) to read the bytes that are already in the internal buffer, without making any read call to the underlying raw stream?  (A would-be "read0" method.)
Typical use case: using socket.socket.makefile to obtain a file-like object on a blocking socket, one wants to be able to read all data available from the socket.  As far as I can see, select.select can help determine whether there is anything more to be read on the socket, but what has already been read from the socket and stored in the internal buffer of the file-like object seems inaccessible if one does not want a blocking read call.

For the described use case of to read all data available from the socket, how do you think one would benefit from using io.BufferedReader? In other words, why use io.BufferedReader here at all?

socket.socket.makefile returns an object of io.BufferedReader class.
So the question arises as soon as one wants to use the file-like object returned by socket.socket.makefile and read all available data.

Of course, and why do you use makefile in the first place?

I happened to be using imaplib and it turns out that imaplib relies on socket.socket.makefile. So the question arises whenever one wants to use imaplib and make sure that after a call to IMAP4.read or IMAP4.readline there is nothing more that is waiting to be processed (in a situation where one does not want to make a blocking read call).

One can also turn the question around: does socket.socket.makefile have any usefulness at all if it is incompatible with non-blocking sockets and does not give any way to read the internal buffer without making a blocking read call?


One can also turn the question around: does socket.socket.makefile have any usefulness at all if it is incompatible with non-blocking sockets and does not give any way to read the internal buffer without making a blocking read call?

Very well, it has: With a blocking socket and a line-oriented protocol, one can conveniently use makefile and readline, and when the protocol is line-oriented, an unterminated line in an internal buffer is not waiting to be processed.

I do not understand how this takes care of the situation where the internal buffer contains a fully terminated line. When using makefile, it can happen that a first call to readline will only return one line but will at the same time load several terminated lines into the internal buffer. One wants to be able to access these already loaded subsequent terminated lines without making a blocking read call.

I answered your question about the usefulness of makefile. I do not understand why One wants to be able to access these already loaded subsequent terminated lines without making a blocking read call. Independently of this, in the normal case where one doesn't want to avoid a blocking read, the answer applies.

"Without making a blocking read call" was specified as part of the original post, in the typical use case--the main question specified "without making any read call to the underlying raw stream", which in the context of makefile amounts to the same.  I believe this is a very normal requirement: one host may need to know whether or not the other host has finished sending data before taking action based on the data received so far.  Example: when monitoring a mailbox through IMAP IDLE, whenever something happens the server will send a few lines--typically 1 or 2, but unpredictably many.

To make the issue with socket.socket.makefile crystal clear, let me rephrase it. A program usually cannot afford to make a blocking read call on a socket forever, and just not do anything more. Apart from multithreading, the only options I can see are (1) non-blocking read calls, (2) blocking read calls with timeouts, (3) checking before any potentially blocking read call whether the call will block or not. However, with socket.socket.makefile, (1) is forbidden, (2) can lead to inconsistent data according to the documentation, and (3) is apparently impossible because of the internal buffer.

I do not share the belief that it is a very normal requirement of IMAP4 to postpone taking action on receipt of an EXISTS response. – What a program cannot afford depends entirely on the application requirements; I don't know what usually shall mean here. If you require it, I agree with your analysis that it isn't possible with io.BufferedReader unless using multithreading.

I understand from your comment that the answer to my original question is "no". This is unfortunate; somehow, socket.socket.makefile, when used, defeats the purpose of select.select. Thank you for your answer!
